# exim4 different passwd.client for different sender or router

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, smtp, exim

I am using exim4 with a couple of smarthosts to send email from my private mail server. I have a default smarthost, but I also use official SMTP relays for accounts using senders from domains handled Google, Outlook and such. The reason is (of course) to get your mail sent from official servers, making it much more likely being accepted by servers using SPF.

If you only have one account handled by, for example, Microsoft servers you can just add the credentials (username for account on domain handled my Microsoft + password) and pattern matching Microsoft SMTP servers in /etc/exim4/passwd.client. However, if you have several accounts all handled by the same servers, how do you handle the situation?

It could probably be handled by configurable auth, but if someone has already found out how, it would be nice to know.

One such router:

```
dnslookup_outlook:
  debug_print = "R: dnslookup_outlook for $local_part@$domain"
  driver = manualroute
  transport = remote_smtp_smarthost
  senders = per-eric.rosen@<one domain>:per-eric.rosen@<completely unrelated domain>
  route_list = * smtp.office365.com::587 bydns ipv4_only
  host_find_failed = defer
  same_domain_copy_routing = yes
  no_more
  condition = ${if match {$sender_host_address} {\N^(|127\.0\.0\.1)$\N}}
```

and passwd.client contains

```
  *.ms-acdc.office.com:<username for one domain>:<password for that>
  ... (more rows for other providers)
  ...
  ...
```

Comment: Hope this link can give you useful information: 
 https://askubuntu.com/questions/167043/how-do-i-configure-exim4-to-send-mail-through-a-password-protected-ssl-smtp-mail

Comment: That's nice and all, but only for regular passwd.client, where you dont have to use several different login/password combination for the same SMTP relay server.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't help you, if you have a solution, remember to share!